# Google Cloud SDK Support Deadline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

When is the support deadline for the Google Cloud SDK?

I'm using Google Cloud SDK v331.0.0.
What is the support period for this version?

Even if I check the GCP site, the support deadline for Google Cloud SDK is not stated, so please tell me the official page that is listed.

Comment: The CLI is a development tool and not a production product/service. I have not seen a published policy. Given how rapidly services are improved and new services created - weekly, I would not stay at a particular version. What works today, might not work in six months. Review the release notes to determine your strategy. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud SDK get regular updates, so instead of big releases, what you get are regular improvements and updates. Consequently, once a new version is released, the previous ones get deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I wanted to see the official page that clearly stated the policy, but it's not there...
If the number of servers is large, maintenance man-hours will be required to upgrade the version every few months...

Comment: Adding to @DavidCarrancio's answer, if you would like to see the official reference about the Cloud SDK update policy, please see the [GCP Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms), part 1.4 - Modifications, point (d): 


> "(d) Discontinuation of Services. Google will notify Customer at least 12 months before discontinuing any Service (or associated material functionality) **unless Google replaces such discontinued Service or functionality with a materially similar Service or functionality**."

Answer (score 0):

Although the terms of the Google Cloud SDK are not explicitly disclosed, I understand that the terms of the Google Cloud Platform apply.
Thanks!